# Why is my python code unable to open pdf file?

Tags: python

I am a beginner at Python, and some time ago, I made a short script that would just open Zoom and a .pdf file with a list of my meeting PMIs and passcodes. This way, I could open them by clicking a shortcut on my desktop. Not the most practical, but I wanted to code it.
I ended up with this code:

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\Hashim\\Desktop\\Zoom")
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\Hashim\\Documents\\meetings.pdf")
```

For a few weeks, it worked quite well. I used it daily, but a few days ago, it stopped opening zoom and the pdf. I don't think this is a problem with the code as it displayed me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Noetic\\Desktop\\Zoom'
```

I know this might be unrelated to Python, but does anyone have any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: Did you move or remove `zoom`  from your desktop?  Check the file path `c:\users\hashim\desktop\zoom` still exists.

Comment: I just tried, but it seems that Desktop is not in C:\Users\Hashim. I never removed Zoom from my desktop, it's still there, but how did Desktop get removed from there?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you further as I do not have a windows OS.  But clearly the problem is the filename: it no longer exists.  I note the different usernames `Noetic` vs `Hashim`.

Comment: I used Noetic in my code, I just typed Hashim here because I am more used to it.

Comment: Try finding the correct path of your application or your file from cmd and paste that path in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `os.startfile()` on zoom using the path of the exe?

something like this might work:

```
import os

os.startfile(os.getenv('APPDATA') + r'\Zoom\bin_00\Zoom.exe')
```

Also make sure Zoom is installed.